# Flyway implement for Springboot fails for sqlserver with error function 'sp_getapplock' expects parameter '@LockMode', which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, migration, flyway

Trying to add flyway migration capability to spring-boot application for multiple databases.

flyway version - 10.1.0
spring boot - 3.2.0

I am trying to introduce and support migrations for multiple databases based upon the datasource configured.
It is working fine for oracle and postgre creating the flyway_schema_history table and executing the migrations
It however fails for SQL Server.
below is my maven pom snippet

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>$10.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-database-oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MSSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.5.0.jre11-preview</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get the below error

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to acquire SQL Server application lock
---------------------------------------------
SQL State  : S0004
Error Code : 201
Message    : Procedure or function 'sp_getapplock' expects parameter '@LockMode', which was not supplied.

                at org.flywaydb.database.sqlserver.SQLServerApplicationLockTemplate.execute(SQLServerApplicationLockTemplate.java:63)
                at org.flywaydb.database.sqlserver.SQLServerConnection.lock(SQLServerConnection.java:93)
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory.create(JdbcTableSchemaHistory.java:104)
                at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.lambda$migrate$0(Flyway.java:199)
                at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:215)
                at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:147)
                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1822)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
                ... 136 more
        Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Procedure or function 'sp_getapplock' expects parameter '@LockMode', which was not supplied.
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:261)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1730)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:653)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:572)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7706)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4201)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:289)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:263)
                at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:549)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
                at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
                at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:190)
                at org.flywaydb.database.sqlserver.SQLServerApplicationLockTemplate.execute(SQLServerApplicationLockTemplate
```

I tried the update of flyway-sqlserver to latest 10.2.0 have cleared my .m2 for any dependency conflict.

I can clearly see that the in the SQLServerApplicationLockTemplate class, when it tries to acquire the Lock

```
        this.jdbcTemplate.execute("EXEC sp_getapplock @Resource = ?, @LockTimeout='3600000', @LockMode = 'Exclusive', @LockOwner = 'Session'", new Object[]{this.lockName});
```

@LockMode is passed on as Exclusive but still getting the same error.

Have already been through

[Procedure or function 'sp_getapplock' expects parameter '@LockMode', which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77628226/procedure-or-function-sp-getapplock-expects-parameter-lockmode-which-was-n)

Thanks for any suggestions and/or help

Comment: What edition and version of SQL Server are you executing the migration against? It's also unlikely to work properly against things like Azure SQL Data Warehouse or Amazon's Babelfish.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM) - 16.0.1000.6 (X64)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `mssql-jdbc`. Rollback to version `12.4.0.jre11` and everything should be fine.